# Hadoop pipes (wordcount) example failing (with hadoop 0.21.0)

Tags: c++, hadoop, pipe

I was trying out the [simplistic word count example for hadoop pipes](http://pastebin.com/xgejUvNC). Unfortunately it is erroring out with `java.lang.NullPointerException` and `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available` errors when I try to run it as:

```
$ bin/hadoop pipes -Dhadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true \
                   -Dhadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true \ 
                   -input <inputHDFSPath> \               
                   -output <outputHDFSPath> \
                   -program <cppBinaryHDFSPath>
```

The error details are [here](http://pastebin.com/dTDjBcMn).

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit1: Added command used to run.

Edit2: It turns out that the C++ binary wasn't statically linked. After rectifying that I am now seeing [this error](http://pastebin.com/kv22sVhd).

Edit3: Added hadoop version being used. I have also added relevant portions of the jobtracker logs [here](http://pastebin.com/vn41fDEk). Also, `stderr` for each of the failed attempts has this:

```
$more /usr/local/dp/hadoop/userlogs/job_201107211831_0013/\
attempt_201107211831_0013_m_‌​000000_0/stderr 
Hadoop Pipes Exception: Aborted by driver
```

Comment: Getting error - when? While compiling, linking, running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I gave it another shot and started from scratch. This time round I had better success. Here is the [code and the config files](http://pastebin.com/XkCSyGHL) I used.

Also, here's the command I used to run the job:

```
hadoop pipes -conf path/to/dp_hpt_conf.xml 
             -input /path/to/input 
             -output /path/to/output
```

The input files in the `/path/to/input` were:

```
$hadoop fs -ls /path/to/input
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 dp dpgrp         25 2011-07-26 23:24 /path/to/input/bar
-rw-r--r--   3 dp dpgrp         87 2011-07-26 23:24 /path/to/input/baz
-rw-r--r--   3 dp dpgrp         44 2011-07-26 23:24 /path/to/input/foo
$hadoop fs -get /path/to/input/foo .
$cat foo 
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

And the output was:

```
$ hadoop fs -get /path/to/output/part-00000 .
$ cat part-00000 
another 3
be      2
brown   2
dog     2
end     2
for     2
fox     2
input   2
is      3
jumps   2
lazy    2
of      2
over    2
program 2
quick   2
sentence        3
should  2
test    2
that    2
the     5
this    4
yet     2
```

(Apologies for the wonky paths. My actual paths were different - the paths here are just my lazy attempts at anonymizing them.)

Answer (score 0):

since it is looking for `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` it seems you mapper is compiled with 64bit compiler, are you sure the jvm is also 64bit?

I have a feeling it is this 64 bit thing which is causing the broken pipes. check on the cluster and the dev machine.

Comment: Just updated the question/problem description - but the C++ binary wasn't statically linked and so was looking for the .so's. After rectifying this, I am seeing [these errors](http://pastebin.com/kv22sVhd).

Comment: can you check the job tracker logs, for each some of these failed attempts and see what it says in stderr section

Comment: I looked at the jobtracker logs, I don't see anything [obvious](http://pastebin.com/vn41fDEk). Also, would you happen to know how to get the JVM to print out the entire stacktrace? Currently it prints out a bunch and then truncates it with `... 7 more`.

Comment: Moreover, the `stderr` for all the attempts just seems to have the following: `$more /usr/local/dp/hadoop/userlogs/job_201107211831_0013/attempt_201107211831_0013_m_000000_0/stderr 
Hadoop Pipes Exception: Aborted by driver`

Comment: you can view the logs for each attempt as well, what do those logs say. for eg. http://<node>:50030/jobfailures.jsp?jobid=job_201107211831_0013&kind=map&cause=killed and then click on 4kb, 8kb or all

Comment: Unfortunately in my setup the web interfaces for namenodes, jobtrackers et al. have been disabled and from what I am told it is non-trivial to modify this setting, re-deploy and bring up the cluster.

Comment: I am not really sure. there is a $HADOOP_LOG_DIR, you can check that. or look at the files in $HADOOP_CONF directory like core-site.xml for hints as to where the logs might be

Comment: Yep, I did check the job/task tracker/namenode logs. Didn't see any thing that could point me in the right direction. Btw, the stacktrace seems to get truncated with `... 7 more` and I was curious is there any way to control/configure this and have it dump out the entire stacktrace?